# Question about a infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could you please explain how come:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty(0.5)^{i+1}(i+1)=2$$

How come the answer is not inf? And why 2?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See [this similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know for $|r|<1$, $$\sum_{1\le i<\infty}r^{i+1}=r^2\cdot\frac1{1-r}=\frac{r^2}{1-r}$$

$$\text{Now, }\frac{d\left(\sum_{1\le i<\infty}r^{i+1}\right)}{dr}=\sum_{1\le i<\infty}\frac{d r^{i+1}}{dr}=\sum_{1\le i<\infty}(i+1)r^i$$

$$\text{and  }\frac{d\left(\frac{r^2}{1-r}\right)}{dr}=\frac{2r-r^2}{(1-r)^2}$$

$$\implies \sum_{1\le i<\infty}(i+1)r^i=\frac{2r-r^2}{(1-r)^2}$$

$$\implies \sum_{1\le i<\infty}(i+1)r^{i+1}=\frac{r(2r-r^2)}{(1-r)^2}$$

Alternatively, using [Arithmetico-geometric series](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Arithmetico-geometric_series),  we can show, $$\sum_{1\le i<\infty}(i+c)r^{i+1}=\frac{(c+1)r^2-c\cdot r^3}{(1-r)^2}$$ where $c$ is any finite number

Let $S=\sum_{1\le i<\infty}(i+c)r^{i+1}$

Multiply either sides by the common ratio $r,$  and subtract from the original

Comment: I'm not sure what you did here and why. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Mankochka, do you know Infinite Geometric Series ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence) with common ratio=$r$? If yes, the  apply derivative wrt $r$

Comment: I understood the proof you linked to, but as it doesn't mention derivatives I don't understand how to apply it to my example, and what are the steps you performed.

Comment: @Mankochka, please find the edited answer

Comment: Finally got it, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You wonder why the sum

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} k \left ( \frac{1}{2}\right)^k$$

does not blow up, presumably because of the factor of $k$ in the sum which grows linearly to $\infty$.  The answer, very roughly, is because the factor of $(1/2)^k$ decreases much more quickly than $k$ increases.

Let's look at a few terms to see how this works.  The first few terms in the sum look like

$$2 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + 3 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^3 + 4 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^4 + \ldots = \frac{2}{4} + \frac{3}{8} + \frac{4}{16}+ \ldots$$

The terms here are already getting smaller at $k=2$.  Now let's double the index:

$$\ldots+\frac{8}{2^8}+\ldots+\frac{16}{2^{16}}+\ldots+\frac{32}{2^{32}}+\ldots$$

You should see that, while the numerator doubles, i.e., exponent increases by $1$, the denominator is squared, i.e., exponent is doubled.

I hope you see that the terms in the series rapidly vanish as $k \rightarrow \infty$.  By comparison with far more slowly varying sequences whose corresponding series converge (e.g., $1/k^2$), this series converges.

It converges to $3/2$ for reasons summarized by @lab above.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers, thanks :)