# proof of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot x^n= \frac{x}{(x-1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I know that the Series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \cdot x^n $ converges to $\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}$ but I'm not sure how to show it. I'm pretty sure that has been asked before, but I wasn't able to find anything...

Comment: Must be one of the most often asked question on the site.

Comment: You’ll find several solutions among the answers to [this very slightly different question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn); at least one of them can be applied directly.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366342/question-about-a-infinite-series and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67364/sequence-sum-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n kx^k$$

Assuming $|x|<1$,
 $$S_n-xS_n=\sum_{k=1}^n x^k-nx^{n+1}=\frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}-nx^{n+1}\Rightarrow S_n=\frac{x(1-x^n)}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Now, if $|x|<1$, then $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)x^{n+1}}{nx^n}\right|=|x|\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=|x|<1$$So, by ratio test, the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n kx^k$ converges and hence $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nx^{n+1}=x\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nx^{n}=0$$

So, $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: please cross check $S_n-x\cdot S_n$

Comment: Sorry, left the last term.

Comment: Although this solution is now accepted, the line with an $\implies$ sign still has several mistakes.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay, I think we still need to derive the value of $n\cdot x^{n+1}$

Comment: Oh, right, we have to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nx^{n+1}=0$, right?

Comment: Still one mistake (extreme right of same line).

Comment: Extremely sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) formula, if $|x|<1, \sum_{1\le r<\infty }x^r=\frac x{1-x}=-\frac1{x-1}-1$

Now, differentiate wrt $x$